# How to change multiple formulas by adding $

Tags: excel, formula

I have a formula in multiple cells that I need to add the $ to and change the $ in other parts of it. See below.

Formula currently looks like:

```
=IF(AND(AE1>=$C$2,AE1<=$D$2),IF($B$2="A","A",IF($B$2="JW","J"," "))," ")
```

I need it to look like:

```
=IF(AND($AE$1>=$C2,$AE$1<=$D2),IF($B2="A","A",IF($B2="JW","J"," "))," ")
```

I need to change it in multiple cells.

Comment: Hi Adam, welcome to StackOverflow. Your question just says "formula".. "formula" for which particular platform/program? e.g., Excel, Python?

Comment: do you have the list of references that has to be changed already? Like `AE1` to `$AE$1` and `$B$2` to `$B2`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make this automatic. But if you are able to change the formula in one cell and cells adjacent to it, you maybe be able to drag the bottom right corner of the cell to make it a bit easier.